# how to select class attributes using C# LINQ

Tags: linq-to-objects

i have the following class :

```
class customer{
public string name  {get;set;}
public attributes MyAttr {get;set;}
}

class attributes
{
public string attr1 {get;set;}
public string attr2 {get;set;}
public string attr3 {get;set;}
}
```

so i have list of customer and i want to get a list of name and attributes to bind to a Gridview ?

Comment: Isn't customer class already a name and a list of attributes? How your new list should look like?

Comment: So you want to bind Customer Name, attr1, attr2 etc in Gridview, right?

Comment: yes that is my goal !

Answer (score 0):

If you have list of customers then loop through it, you will get name and attributes.

```
foreach(customer customer in Customers)
{
     String name = customer.name;
     String attr1 = customer.MyAttr.attr1
     String attr2 = customer.MyAttr.attr2
     String attr3 = customer.MyAttr.attr3  
}
```

For simple looping, no need of LINQ.

Comment: unfortunately i can not iterate through the attributes like that !

Comment: @RedaBakr check my answer, I hope it helps.

Comment: @RedaBakr: I have corrected little bit. See the updated answer. Now you should be able to loop through

Answer (score 0):

```
...
var nameAndAttr = listCustomers
    .Select(c =>
        new
        {
            Name = c.name,
            Attributes = new[] {c.MyAttr.attr1, c.MyAttr.attr2, c.MyAttr.attr3}
        });
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor your `attributes` class to be enumerable:

```
class attributes : IEnumerable<string>
{
    public string attr1 {get;set;}
    public string attr2 {get;set;}
    public string attr3 {get;set;}

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new List<string> { attr1, attr2, attr3 }.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Then you can use regular linq queries with it:

```
var attrs = myCustomer.Attributes.Where(attr => attr.StartsWith("foo"));
```

And a binding would look like this:

```
myGridView.DataSource = myCustomer.Attributes;
```

If you can't modify the `attributes` class you can write an extension method for it:

```
static class attributesExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> Enumerate(this attributes attributes)
    {
        yield return attributes.attr1;
        yield return attributes.attr2;
        yield return attributes.attr3;
    }
}
```

And use linq like this:

```
var attrs = myCustomer.Attributes.Enumerate().Where(attr => attr.StartsWith("foo"));
```

And a binding would look like this:

```
myGridView.DataSource = myCustomer.Attributes.Enumerate();
```

Comment: Thanks , I used the extension method but how to access it inside lambda expression , i want to do it like that : result.Select(a=> new { a.UnitName,a.UnitFactors.Enumrate()} );

Comment: To stay with the example above: `listOfCustomers.Select(c => new[] { c.name }.Concat(c.MyAttr.Enumerate())`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind the Customer Name, attributes in GridView, try something like this.

```
   List<customer> lstCustomers = new List<customer>();

   lstCustomers.Add(new customer 
     { 
        name = "Name", 
        MyAttr = new attributes 
             { 
                attr1 = "attr1", attr2 = "attr2", attr3 = "attr3" 
              } 
       });

   var result = lstCustomers
                  .Select(x => new 
                         { 
                           x.name, x.MyAttr.attr1, x.MyAttr.attr2, x.MyAttr.attr3 
                         });

   GridView2.DataSource = result;
   GridView2.DataBind();
```